# jQuery problems with mobile website

Tags: android, jquery, html, mobile, tablet

I have a question about JQuery. I am trying to design a mobile portion of my site and I am running into a bug. So I have CSS for 3 different screen sizes (480,tablet type, and default). The mobile version has more of a tile layout with jQuery in it but I only want it to work with the mobile 480 screen size. I do that by this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 481) {
```

The bug I am finding is if I am on my phone and load the site in portrait mode, then turn my screen to go to landscape mode, the css updates correctly so it doesn't do the tile type anymore but more of columns, but then jQuery is still working where I can toggle things I don't want to toggle for that size, only the tile setting. Is there anyway to do this? If I load my site on landscape mode the jQuery doesn't load (which is good), it is only when I switch. I know this is because it checks the screen size at the page load but anyone have ideas of workarounds?

Comment: Run through your `if` test again right before doing the code for toggle.

Comment: Are you running media queries in css on the same resolution?

Comment: Yeah, it the CSS works great, but I have jquery doing some toggling to make it easier on the mobile version but that means some of my content is missing when you switch to landscape mode because you have to toggle it to be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using media queries for the same resolution, here's what I do.

In your Jquery, test for a media query change. For example, let's say you have this:

```
 @media (max-width: 480px) { 
      #someDiv {
          display:none;
     }
 }
```

In your JQuery you can then do this:

```
 if($("#someDiv").css("display") == "none") {
     // do whatever you want in Javascript that will only be run if that css media query is triggered
 }
```

Comment: Testing for a media query change sounds like exactly what I need to do, Would you be able to explain a bit? Not to sound dumb but if I set display:none; isnt it not gonna even show?

Comment: It was just an example of how to see in your javascript if your media query was triggered. I didn't mean do exactly that. In YOUR JS test for something you did change in YOUR media query.